# UIKeyboardDidShowNotification called in two ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsnotificationcenter

I have one view controller (UICollectionView) that contains textfields. In this controller I listen for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`:s. Like this:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

And in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
    [...]
```

In another view controller I have a `UITextView`. This controller also listens for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. Before I push this second view controller I remove the first view controller as an observer:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

But when the keyboard appears in `VC2`, then the `keyboardDidShow` actions also gets called in `VC1`, causing unwanted animations. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour somehow?

**Update**
The strange thing is that the notification actions in `VC1` gets called when I tap the back button in `VC2`.

Comment: Have you put an NSLog in viewWillDisappear to see if it is getting called the way you want it to? (IE when the view goes away).

Comment: I have added a break point and it always gets called.

Comment: Are ones in VC1 only being called when you tap the back button, or are they also called while in VC2 and the keyboard changes?

Comment: I only see this behavior (and only for keyboardWillBeHidden) if you tap the back button while the keyboard is still up in vc2. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, the kayeboard is usually up when I tap the back button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Before I push this second view controller I remove the first view controller as an observer:

Maybe that is not what is happening. In fact, it seems to me that it is impossible that `viewWillDisappear` comes before pushing.

I am not sure but when you push a new view controller and the keyboard comes up right away, maybe the notification is fired before the other view did disappear.

You could try removing the observer when you initiated the push (e.g. in `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: Solved it by moving `[self registerForKeyboardNotifications]` to `viewDidAppear` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that in VC2 you show the keyboard in loadView or viewDidLoad， so the order is： VC2 viewDidLoad，keyboardShow，VC1 viewWillDisappear。

So in keyboardDidShow method, you can do something only when the visibleController is self.

In addition, I don't think you should handle this notification in viewWillDisappear or viewWillDisappear, try a better way. And you must removeObserver in dealloc method.